# Parse plain text API response into JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing, text-parsing

An API endpoint that I am using for a project returns a plain text response of the form:

```
[RESPONSE]
code = 200
description = Command completed successfully
queuetime = 0
runtime = 0.071
property[abuse policy][0] = The policies are published at the REGISTRY_OPERATOR website at:
property[abuse policy][1] = =>https://registry.in/Policies 
property[abuse policy][2] = 
property[abuse policy][3] = IN Policy Framework: https://registry.in/system/files/inpolicy_0.pdf
property[abuse policy][4] = IN Domain Anti-Abuse policy: https://registry.in/Policies/IN_Anti_Abuse_Policy
property[abuse policy url][0] = https://registry.in/Policies/IN_Anti_Abuse_Policy
property[active][0] = 0
```

And I am attempting to parse this into a dictionary using Python. Currently, I have the following code:

```
import re
def text_to_dict(text):
    js = {}
    for s in text.splitlines():
        x = s.split("=", maxsplit=1)
        if len(x) > 1:
            keys = [k for i in re.split("\]|\[", x[0]) if (k := i.strip())]
            for i, k in enumerate(keys):
                pd = js
                for j,pk in enumerate(keys[:i]):
                    if keys[j+1:j+2] and not (keys[j+1:j+2][0]).isnumeric():
                        pd = pd[pk]
                if k not in pd:
                    if k.isnumeric():
                        pd[keys[i-1]].append((x[1]).strip())
                    else:
                        pd[k] = (x[1]).strip() if i == len(keys)-1 else [] if keys[i+1:i+2] and (keys[i+1:i+2][0]).isnumeric() else {}
    return js
```

This code can handle the above example, and it returns:

```
{
    "code": "200",
    "description": "Command completed successfully",
    "runtime": "0.081",
    "queuetime": "0",
    "property": {
        "abuse policy": [
            "The policies are published at the REGISTRY_OPERATOR website at:",
            "=>https://registry.in/Policies",
            "",
            "IN Policy Framework: https://registry.in/system/files/inpolicy_0.pdf",
            "IN Domain Anti-Abuse policy: https://registry.in/Policies/IN_Anti_Abuse_Policy"
        ],
        "abuse policy url": [
            "https://registry.in/Policies/IN_Anti_Abuse_Policy"
        ],
        "active": [
            "0"
        ]
    }
}
```

However, it cannot handle the following if I append it to the example above:

```
...
property[active][1][test] = TEST
```

or

```
...
property[active][1][0] = TEST
```

which should return

```
{
    ...
    "active": [
            "0",
            {"test": "TEST"}
        ]
}
```

and

```
{
    ...
    "active": [
            "0",
            ["TEST"]
        ]
}
```

respectively.

I feel like there is an easier way of accounting for all possibilities without writing a bunch of nested ifs, but I'm not sure what is is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input data is practically in INI file format. Python has the `configparser` module for convenience.

When we presume that every part of the key `'property[foo][0][test]'` actually is a dict key (no nested lists), we would parse that into this structure:

```
{'property': {'foo': {'0': {'test': 'value'}}}}
```

which can be done with a loop that keeps creating nested dicts:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

def parse(text):
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read_string(text)

    root = {}
    for key in config['RESPONSE'].keys():
        curr = root
        for key_part in key.replace(']', '').split('['):
            if key_part not in curr:
                curr[key_part] = {}
            prev = curr
            curr = curr[key_part]
        prev[key_part] = config['RESPONSE'][key]
    return root
```

usage

```
from pprint import pprint

text = """
[RESPONSE]
code = 200
description = Command completed successfully
queuetime = 0
runtime = 0.071
property[abuse policy][0] = The policies are published at the REGISTRY_OPERATOR website at:
property[abuse policy][1] = =>https://registry.in/Policies 
property[abuse policy][2] = 
property[abuse policy][3] = IN Policy Framework: https://registry.in/system/files/inpolicy_0.pdf
property[abuse policy][4] = IN Domain Anti-Abuse policy: https://registry.in/Policies/IN_Anti_Abuse_Policy
property[abuse policy url][0] = https://registry.in/Policies/IN_Anti_Abuse_Policy
property[active][0] = 0
property[foo][0][test] = a
property[foo][1][test] = b
property[bar][0][0] = A
property[bar][1][1] = B
"""

pprint(parse(text))
```

result

```
{'code': '200',
 'description': 'Command completed successfully',
 'property': {'abuse policy': {'0': 'The policies are published at the '
                                    'REGISTRY_OPERATOR website at:',
                               '1': '=>https://registry.in/Policies',
                               '2': '',
                               '3': 'IN Policy Framework: '
                                    'https://registry.in/system/files/inpolicy_0.pdf',
                               '4': 'IN Domain Anti-Abuse policy: '
                                    'https://registry.in/Policies/IN_Anti_Abuse_Policy'},
              'abuse policy url': {'0': 'https://registry.in/Policies/IN_Anti_Abuse_Policy'},
              'active': {'0': '0'},
              'bar': {'0': {'0': 'A'}, '1': {'1': 'B'}},
              'foo': {'0': {'test': 'a'}, '1': {'test': 'b'}}},
 'queuetime': '0',
 'runtime': '0.071'}
```

You could check if `key_part` is numeric, and convert it to `int` so the resulting structure behaves more like it contained lists, i.e.

```
{'property': {'foo': {0: {'test': 'value'}}}}
```

Comment: +1 for the ConfigParser suggestion; that saves some parsing. However, I do not want to make the assumption that every part of the key is a dict key, but instead allow for nested lists.

Comment: @2abysses Every part of the key *is* a string. What you make of it is your own decision. See my suggestion below the code - this is easy enough to do and mimics nested lists good enough to be useful in practice. You don't really need nested lists. Think about it for a moment.

Comment: @2abysses What I'm saying is - treating every part of the key as a dict key is *stable*. There is no way this can ever go wrong. Introducing list semantics makes the whole thing unstable. What if `properties[test][1]` is in the data, but `properties[test][0]` isn't? Lists can't do that. Dicts can. Assuming the server is benign and that never happens, then the result (`data['properties']['test']`) behaves *exactly* like a list, and there is nothing to gain from making it a list. If it *can* happen, then `data['properties']['test'][1]` can exist without requiring `[0]` to be there.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.